# why python tracebacks at self.collectionFile=param[1]

Tags: python

Hi I'm beginner in python and I'm trying to execute this program to create an inverted index for a collection file:

```
import sys
import re
from porterStemmer import PorterStemmer
from collections import defaultdict
from array import array
import gc

porter=PorterStemmer()

class CreateIndex:
    def __init__(self):
        self.index=defaultdict(list)    #the inverted index


    def getStopwords(self):
        '''get stopwords from the stopwords file'''
        f=open(self.stopwordsFile, 'r')
        stopwords=[line.rstrip() for line in f]
        self.sw=dict.fromkeys(stopwords)
        f.close()


    def getTerms(self, line):
        '''given a stream of text, get the terms from the text'''
        line=line.lower()
        line=re.sub(r'[^a-z0-9 ]',' ',line) #put spaces instead of non-alphanumeric characters
        line=line.split()
        line=[x for x in line if x not in self.sw]  #eliminate the stopwords
        line=[ porter.stem(word, 0, len(word)-1) for word in line]
        return line


    def parseCollection(self):
        ''' returns the id, title and text of the next page in the collection '''
        doc=[]
        for line in self.collFile:
            if line=='</page>\n':
                break
            doc.append(line)

        curPage=''.join(doc)
        pageid=re.search('<id>(.*?)</id>', curPage, re.DOTALL)
        pagetitle=re.search('<title>(.*?)</title>', curPage, re.DOTALL)
        pagetext=re.search('<text>(.*?)</text>', curPage, re.DOTALL)

        if pageid==None or pagetitle==None or pagetext==None:
            return {}

        d={}
        d['id']=pageid.group(1)
        d['title']=pagetitle.group(1)
        d['text']=pagetext.group(1)

        return d


    def writeIndexToFile(self):
        '''write the inverted index to the file'''
        f=open(self.indexFile, 'w')
        for term in self.index.iterkeys():
            postinglist=[]
            for p in self.index[term]:
                docID=p[0]
                positions=p[1]
                postinglist.append(':'.join([str(docID) ,','.join(map(str,positions))]))
            print >> f, ''.join((term,'|',';'.join(postinglist)))

        f.close()


    def getParams(self):
        '''get the parameters stopwords file, collection file, and the output index file'''
        param=sys.argv
        self.stopwordsFile=param[0]
        self.collectionFile=param[1]
        self.indexFile=param[2]


    def createIndex(self):
        '''main of the program, creates the index'''
        self.getParams()
        self.collFile=open(self.collectionFile,'r')
        self.getStopwords()

        #bug in python garbage collector!
        #appending to list becomes O(N) instead of O(1) as the size grows if gc is enabled.
        gc.disable()

        pagedict={}
        pagedict=self.parseCollection()
        #main loop creating the index
        while pagedict != {}:
            lines='\n'.join((pagedict['title'],pagedict['text']))
            pageid=int(pagedict['id'])
            terms=self.getTerms(lines)

            #build the index for the current page
            termdictPage={}
            for position, term in enumerate(terms):
                try:
                    termdictPage[term][1].append(position)
                except:
                    termdictPage[term]=[pageid, array('I',[position])]

            #merge the current page index with the main index
            for termpage, postingpage in termdictPage.iteritems():
                self.index[termpage].append(postingpage)

            pagedict=self.parseCollection()


        gc.enable()

        self.writeIndexToFile()


if __name__=="__main__":
    c=CreateIndex()
    c.createIndex()
```

and it tracebacks

> File "C:\Users\createIndex.py", line 119, in
>
> c.createIndex()
>
> File "C:\Users\createIndex.py", line 81, in createIndex
>
> self.getParams()

> File "C:\Users\createIndex.py", line 75, in getParams
>
> self.collectionFile=param[1]
>
> IndexError: list index out of range

why Python tracebacks at these line and
what should I do to fix this ??